# Dealing with complex, nested types in API

Tags: c++, types, architecture, api-design, naming

So let's assume that there's a project related to image processing. We've got an algorithm that calculates "scores" (no matter what it is) between two images so:

```
double score(Image i1, Image i2)
```

If we have multiple frames (images), we want to calculate it for all of them (matching all to all):

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, double>> score(std::vector<Image> images); // [1]
```

(*pairs of ints represent image indices in images vector because we match all to all*)

Unfortunately, we get our images from many devices where each of them can have multiple streams (and then multiple, consecutive frames from each stream), which makes it complicated to this level:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, double>>>>
     ^devices    ^streams    ^frames     ^score   ^image indices
```

How would you deal with a function that has to return such complex type?

It is only about wrapping it in typedefs and naming properly? Or maybe you would only let the user use simpler version of API i.e. with one vector [1] and further wrap it on their own? Or maybe is there any fancy pattern for such case?

Comment: Did you miss second `std::pair` in `[1]`?

Comment: Typedefs (i.e. `using X = Y;`) should be the first step to keeping it readable. But that's only if the design itself is sound, which is hard to judge (don't you want to wrap each level of collection in some sort of class that provides other useful things?)...

Comment: if it's API, I don't really see the reason for the `device/stream/frames` parameter... `score()` should not care about them. And for `score(std::vector<Image> images)`, I personally would return a 2D array (custom class or `vector<vector<double>>`)

Comment: Yes I did, thank you @Evg

Answer (score 1):

In general, you deal with complexity by giving proper names to things.

When I see your API in `[1]`, I see a graph, where the images are the nodes of the graph and you return the edges as an adjacency list. The adjacency information can also be stored in the form of a symmetric adjacency matrix. Having the proper terminology for your problem, might give you access to a vast set of tools, e.g. libraries like Boost.Graph. It might be the starting point for you to write your own reusable components. You may even find out that people dealt with problems that you are trying to solve, but in more abstract terms.

This is just one option and when you think about naming things right, wonderful things can happen.

Regarding your second jump in complexity, I'd argue that it might be up to the caller to decide on the size of the chunks they want to feed into your algorithm, because this seems to artificially limit the use case of your function. If you think, this is not the case, you still should give proper names to the things. You can use structs and classes for it, a choice that is probably quite poor:

```
using AdjacencyList = std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, double>;
// Info that might also be represented as a matrix or symmetric matrix.

class SimilarityData
{
    public:
        const AdjacencyList &
        getAdjacencyList(
            int device,
            int stream,
            int frame ) const;
};
```

Comment: I agree, this seems to limit the use case of the function. I'll consider either providing only less-complex function (e.g taking only single pair) or maybe both overloaded.

Comment: @Mateusz Great! Just consider the possibility that the more complex overload might belong into the calling code that uses your function in that particular way. Given that you have a lot of additional context at that level, it should be easier to figure out the proper names there. If there are really multiple independent callers that use your function in one particular way, it should also become a lot easier to come up with proper names.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about the data, one option is to create structs or classes to wrap the individual parts:

```
namespace your_company {
struct index {
    std::pair<int, int> indexes;
};
struct frame {
    std::pair<index, double> scores;
};
struct stream {
    std::vector<frame> frames;
};
struct device {
    std::vector<stream> streams;
};
}
```

You can even add more info to the structs if needed. Such as:

```
struct device {
    std::vector<stream> streams;
    std::string name;
};
```

So then your function would return a `device`. The user code might look like:

```
your_company::device d = your_function();
d.streams[0].frames[0].scores[0].pair[0].....
```

Comment: Indeed, it can be cleaner than a lot of nested types, but I'm afraid of introducing a lot of new structures just for this purpose.